# Link disappears after saving a form using Telerik RadAjaxPanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik, panel

I have a problem with RadAjaxPanel from Telerik. I have a single LinkButton in a master page that I'm moving around in the DOM using some JavaScript/jQuery after the page has loaded. The problem begins when I move the link into a RadAjaxPanel. When the user then save the form in this ajax panel the **link gets removed from the DOM** for some reason.

Is this a know issue with RadAjaxPanel and the Telerik components? What am I missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the same happen when you move the button inside MS UpdatePanel instead of telerik ajax panel? I think that such DOM manipulations/relocations do not play nice with MS AJAX in general.

Comment: You are right, the same thing happens. Thanks for the information.